# How long can a water heater be without a water supply before it might be damaged?

Tags: basement

Because of a busted feed pipe my water has been turned off since mid December 2014.  I've had the temperature on my water heater turned down to Low (but not Pilot) since then.  Since I'm still not sure when I can get my water feed line fixed, I'm wondering if there is damage or long before there might be damage to my water heater.  I will probably turn it completely off today, but still would like to know how long it would take before a problem arises with a tank that is either 50 gallons or 76 gallons.

Comment: why would you pay to keep heating the water in the tank if you can't use it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the water heater is completely full of water, indefinitely. The fact that there isn't fresh water flowing through it regularly isn't particularly important (and will likely even extend it's lifespan). If too much air enters the tank however, when the heater fires the lifespan will drop down into minutes or even seconds.